# ERRORLEVEL env variable updates in batch script, but %ERRORLEVEL% does not

Tags: cmd.exe, runtime-error

I have the following batch script that runs on an ftp server.  I use a scheduler that passes 4 variables; SouRCe, EXTension, DESTination, and ZIP Directory.  It's a simple script that requires the first 3 variables, but the user can omit the last 4th one, if they do not need to zip the files.

```
@ECHO OFF

SET SRC=%1
SET EXT=%2
SET DEST=%3
SET ZIPD=%4
SET DTE=%DATE:~4,2%%DATE:~7,2%%DATE:~10,4%
FOR /F "TOKENS=1-3 DELIMS=: " %%L IN ('TIME /T') DO SET hhmm=%%L%%M%

DIR /B /A:-d %SRC%
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
        ECHO *** There are no files to process. *** RC=%ERRORLEVEL%
    SET ERRORLEVEL=0
        GOTO EXIT
)

DEL /Q %SRC%\Thumbs.db

IF DEFINED ZIPD (
    WZZIP %ZIPD%\%DTE%%hhmm%.zip %SRC%\*%EXT%
    IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
        ECHO *** WZZIP for "%SRC%\*%EXT%" failed. *** RC=%ERRORLEVEL%
        ECHO.
        GOTO EXIT
    )
    ECHO.
    ECHO successfully zipped %SRC% TO %ZIPD%: %DTE%%hhmm%.zip
    ECHO.
)

MOVE /Y %SRC%\*%EXT% %DEST%
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
    ECHO ** MOVE "%SRC%\*%EXT%" TO "%DEST%"  Failed. *** RC=%ERRORLEVEL%
)

:EXIT
EXIT /B %ERRORLEVEL%
```

The issue I am encountering is that if nothing is in the directory at 8:15am(Scheduler runs it),

```
DIR /B /A:-d %SRC%
```

fails with a errorlevel of 1. It goes into the loop and exits.  The test for errorlevel work both as

```
IF ERRORLEVEL 1
```

and as

```
IF NOT %ERRORLEVEL% == 0
```

The issue I am encountering is that any subsequent failures are not updating the user variable of %ERRORLEVEL%.  This is why I HAVE to use
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 for the other checks.  Now if WZZIP fails, it goes into the loop following the command, but the ECHO message spits out "RC=0" even though ERRORLEVEL had to be greater-than-or-equal to 1 and as such should have updated %ERRORLEVEL% to whatever it is supposed to be.  I tested the script adding

```
ECHO %ERRORLEVEL%
```

to every other line just to see the changes and even though the DIR test updates %ERRORLEVEL% correctly, again DEL of the thumb.db, which fails 99.999% of the time, comes back %ERRORLEVEL% = 0 and WZZIP if forced to fail also comes out RC=0.  Tried SETLOCAL, SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS, and a bunch of other stuff, even tried removing everything but the WZZIP part and still it does not update %ERRORLEVEL%.
It is an FTP server, that we are constantly running scripts to transfer files, so I was wondering if maybe there is some conflict with other cmd streams changing the env variable as I am running my script?
Additionally, most of the other scripts were not written by me and they LOVE using `SET ERRORLEVEL=whatevernumber` and I know this has caused me conflicts in the past.  I'm wondering if this could be the culprit.

Comment: Read [Delayed Expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html), google _"delayed expansion trap"_  for examples.

Answer (score 1):

You need [Delayed Expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) if you want to use a variable, that you changed in the same command block. (A *command block* is a series of commands within parentheses `(` and `)`.) Delayed variables are referenced using `!var!` instead of `%var%`.

**Example**:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
cmd /C exit /B 99
echo before ^(command block^) %%errorlevel%%=%errorlevel% ^^!errorlevel^^!=!errorlevel!
(
  (call)
  echo ^(inside command block^) %%errorlevel%%=%errorlevel% ^^!errorlevel^^!=!errorlevel!
  (call )
  echo ^(inside command block^) %%errorlevel%%=%errorlevel% ^^!errorlevel^^!=!errorlevel!
)
echo  after ^(command block^) %%errorlevel%%=%errorlevel%  ^^!errorlevel^^!=!errorlevel!
```

**Output**:

```
==> D:\bat\SU\1113027.bat
before (command block) %errorlevel%=99 !errorlevel!=99
(inside command block) %errorlevel%=99 !errorlevel!=1
(inside command block) %errorlevel%=99 !errorlevel!=0
 after (command block) %errorlevel%=0  !errorlevel!=0
```

The `(call)` and `(call )` tricks stolen from [this Dbenham's answer to *setting ERRORLEVEL to 0*](https://superuser.com/a/649329/376602) question:

> *If you want to force the `errorlevel` to* `0`*, then you can use this totally non-intuitive, but very effective syntax:* `(call )`*. The space
>   after call is critical. If you want to set the `errorlevel` to* `1`*,
>   you can use* `(call)`*. It is critical that there not be any space after
>   call.*