# Wrong errorlevel inside parenthesis in Windows batch script

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file, cmd.exe, script

Here is a windows .bat file:

```
@echo off

call :label
echo %errorlevel%
pause >nul
exit

:label
exit /b 1
```

Works as expected and outputs `1`.

but on changing the code to:

```
@echo off

if 1==1 (
    call :label
    echo %errorlevel%
    )
pause >nul
exit

:label
exit /b 1
```

the output is `0` instead of `1`.

The `if 1==1` is just to show the result but I need to use another if statement in the actual script. Why is this happening and what is the solution? If delayed expansion is the solution, how to use it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### If delayed expansion is the solution, how to use it?

As follows:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
if 1==1 (
    call :label
    echo !errorlevel!
    )
pause >nul
endlocal
exit
:label
exit /b 1
```

> Delayed Expansion will cause variables within a batch file to be
> expanded at execution time rather than at parse time, this option is
> turned on with the `SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion` command.

Source: - [EnableDelayedExpansion - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)

You need to replace `%` with `!` to take advantage of delayed expansion.

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line | SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/)
- [Windows CMD Commands (categorized) - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [EnableDelayedExpansion - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)
- [Endlocal - Local environment variables - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/endlocal.html)
- [Setlocal - Local variables - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/setlocal.html)